# IIS 8.0 integrated pipeline Session RequestAcquireState

Tags: session, iis, pipeline, locked, integrated

We are trying to make a cut over from IIS 6.0 to IIS 8.0 Integrated pool on Windows Server 2012 Standard edition for an application built on ASP.Net Version 4.0. Our web application requests go into a RequestAcquireState ( ASP.Net Session gets locked for concurrent requests working with the same sessionid ) , in IIS 8.0 Integrated pool on the above Windows Server . However this behavior does not show up when we run the same app in Classic mode on IIS 8.0 .

Session is stored InProc.

We can rectify this situation on a Windows Server 2012 Data Center by modifying SessionStateLockedItemPollInterval in registry. However that solution does not work in Windows Server 2012 Standard edition.

This has left us perplexed -

why does an ASP.Net Run time Session issue surface in IIS 8.0 Integrated Pool for an application we have run successfully on previous versions of IIS and classic mode in IIS 8.0 ?

How do we rectify this problem now on Windows Server 2012 Standard edition ?

Thanks, will appreciate if some body can help

Comment: Please check the following also; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570855/requests-hanging-on-session-module-on-iis-7-5/27481000#27481000

Answer (score 1):

IIS 8 comes with .net framwork 4.5 so you may be running into missing the fix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2828842

Issue 6

Symptoms

When you send many concurrent requests that have the same SessionId to an ASP.NET 4.5 web application, some requests may freeze at the RequestAcquireState stage unexpectedly.
Resolution

After you apply the hotfix, the hotfix makes sure that the EndRequest event will always trigger.

try installing this fix and see if that addressed the issue